# Pythonic way of creating list of lists from list

Tags: python, list

I would like to create a list of lists from a list.

The list looks like this:

```
level = ['   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C                  E']
```

I need to create this:

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', 'W', ' ', 'C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'W'], ['C', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'E']]
```

I have done it this way:

```
listofLists = []
for row in level:
  liss = []
  for col in row:
    liss.append(col)
  listofLists.append(liss)
```

What is a more pythonic way or shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> listofLists = map(list,level)
```

(in python3, if you really need a list, do `list(map(list, level))`)

Comment: What a timing!!! I have to even pass an "I am a human" test to be able to answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `list()` on a string this will return the list of all its characters (including spaces).

```
level = ['   WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C  W C             W', 'C                  E']
trasnsformed = [list(x) for x in level]
```